# How to reset ClickOnce for a project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I have a normal project and use ClickOnce. Today, following a new implementation, ClickOnce did not work. So I used a setup. Now that the day is over and that I have spent several hours trying to fix ClickOnce by every possible mean, it simply won't work. It publishes fine, but when installing from there, it says that it stopped functionning with the following error:

```
Microsoft .NET ClickOnce Utility stopped functionning
```

Is there a way I could just reset all ClickOnce to default like I never used it? I can't find any, but it has to exist.

Thank you!

Comment: are you running the ClickOnce on the same development box or a client machine?

Comment: On the same development box. It is also where the application is published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After A LOT of trial and error, I ended up fixing the issue. In the project's properties/security menue, I unchecked the 'Activate ClickOnce security parameters' and published. It did recheck the box by itself, but the application published and launched successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Try

1. Verify that the deployment is correctly signed.
2. Verify that "Enable ClickOnce security settings is checked" and "This is a full trust application".
3. In publish tab, verify that you have the correct prerequisites checked, nothing more, nothing less.
4. Verify that the correct application files are checked and set to required. I find when I have "myaplication.exe.manifest" unchecked my users get some serious XML errors.
5. Make sure you use the correct paths in the "publishing folder" and "installation folder". I also find this throwing XML errors when something is incorrect.
6. Go into your windows profile temp folder and delete everything. I use a tool called CCleaner (free tool)...

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, it did not fix my issue. I'll post my solution whenever I figure it out

Comment: Then try to repair the version of the .NET framework you are using or, create a new solution, new project and import all your files into the new project, whack the old one and go from there....are you doing version control?